# VMware 6.7 Mount NFS from Server 2016

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, windows-server-2016

I have a 2016 server that has a iSCSI drive from QNAP shared as a NFS Mount

When I run the command from the VMWare cli:

```
[root@localhost:~] esxcli storage nfs add -H 192.168.1.20 -s vmwaredatastore -v shareddatastore
```

I get the following error

```
Unable to complete Sysinfo operation.  Please see the VMkernel log file for more details.: Sysinfo error: Bad parameterSee VMkernel log for details.
```

If I try to attach the NFS share as a datastore from the esxi GUI or vCenter GUI I get the same error

From the vmkernal.log

```
2020-10-01T08:31:59.783Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)World: 11943: VC opID esxcli-c7-290b maps to vmkernel opID 6cdf2f9b
2020-10-01T08:31:59.783Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)NFS: 160: Command: (mount) Server: (192.168.1.20) IP: (192.168.1.20) Path: (vmwaredatastore) Label: (shareddatastore) Options: (None)
2020-10-01T08:31:59.784Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)StorageApdHandler: 977: APD Handle 6488d328-d7d9d13a Created with lock[StorageApd-0x4311cd3b76d0]
2020-10-01T08:31:59.784Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)SunRPC: 1099: Destroying world 0x402cbc
2020-10-01T08:31:59.785Z cpu0:2098060)WARNING: NFS: 221: Got error 22 from mount call
2020-10-01T08:31:59.785Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)SunRPC: 1099: Destroying world 0x402cbd
2020-10-01T08:31:59.785Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)StorageApdHandler: 1063: Freeing APD handle 0x4311cd3b76d0 [6488d328-d7d9d13a]
2020-10-01T08:31:59.785Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)StorageApdHandler: 1147: APD Handle freed!
2020-10-01T08:31:59.785Z cpu7:2099026 opID=6cdf2f9b)NFS: 221: NFS mount 192.168.1.20:vmwaredatastore status: Bad parameter
```

I can ping the host and connect on port 2049 and 111

```
[root@localhost:~] nc -z 192.168.1.20 2049
Connection to 192.168.1.20 2049 port [tcp/nfs] succeeded!
[root@localhost:~] nc -z 192.168.1.20 111
Connection to 192.168.1.20 111 port [tcp/sunrpc] succeeded!
```

I have googled around and cannot figure out what the "Bad parameter" is

Screenshots from the host

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]